# Can a holomorphic function vanish at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Can a holomorphic function on a non-compact complex manifold vanish at infinity?

If the manifold is a complex domain, this cannot happen because of the maximum principle. But what about the general case?

Comment: What do you mean by "infinity" on a general complex manifold?

Comment: @mrf Being a non-compact manifold, he probably means the limit as $x \to \infty$ on the one-point compactification (i.e, limit w.r.t complements of compact sets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the open mapping theorem is locally true, any nonconstant holomorphic map $M \to \Bbb C$ is open (even though it's a general complex manifold); so apply this by considering an exhaustion of $M$ by compact codimension 0 submanifold $M_n$. The maximum modulus principle for compact complex manifolds with boundary still follows from the open mapping theorem (if the maximum was on the interior, we see that the map can't possibly be open if nonconstant). If $f$ vanishes at infinity, then for large enough $n$, $f(\partial M_n)$ is arbitrarily small; in particular, if $f$ is not identically zero, then $f$ does not achieve its maximum on $\partial M_n$ for $n$ large, contradicting the maximum modulus principal.

Comment: Thank you! A little remark: we don't need $M_n$ to be submanifolds, any countable compact covering, such that $M_n$ is contained in the interior of $M_{n+1}$ will do.